# Ellipsoid set definitions

Tags: convex-optimization, ellipsoids

In Boyd & Vandenberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), one can find two definitions for the ellipsoid.

$$ \mathcal{E} = \left \{ x \mid (x-x_c)^\mathsf{T}P^{-1}(x-x_c) \leq 1 \right\} $$

and

$$ \mathcal{E} = \left \{ x_c+Au \,|\, \| u \| \leq 1 \right \} $$

where $A=P^{1/2}$. I would like to know how to go from the first definition to the second and vice versa. In my doubts, I created a small program with a simple 2d ellipsoid with both definitions to verify that both definitions are the same. I obtained the following image.

[image: Set with random points]

If you are curios you can see the code in the following [link](https://gist.github.com/silgon/52cf14d38015969f2e02a7469fbb699c).

This is how I convinced myself that both definitions of $\mathcal{E}$ are the same. But I'm not able to go from one definition to the other.

The only thing I could do is to pass from the second definition to

$$
\mathcal{E} = \left \{ x \mid \| A^{-1} (x-x_c) \|_2 \leq 1 \right \}
$$

But I'm not sure if that helps of if it helps at all.

Comment: Well, then you did all the work, because $\|v\|_2^2=v^Tv$.

Comment: Note that B&V also assume that $P$ is symmetric, positive definite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a vector $u \in \mathbb R^3$, the following statements are equivalent:

- $\| u \| \leq 1$
- $(x - x_c)^T P (x - x_c) \leq 1$, where $x := x_c + A u$.

Indeed, with $x$ defined to be $x_c + A u$, we have
$$ (x - x_c)^T P (x - x_c) = u^T A^T P A u = u^T A P A u = u^T P^{-1/2} PP^{-1/2} u = u^T u = \| u \|^2,$$
so certainly, $\| u \| \leq 1$ is true if and only if $(x - x_c)^T P (x - x_c) \leq 1$.

Therefore, $\left \{ x_c+Au \,|\, \| u \| \leq 1 \right \} $ is precisely the same set as $ \left \{ x \mid (x-x_c)^\mathsf{T}P^{-1}(x-x_c) \leq 1 \right\} $.

Comment: thanks @Kenny, pretty clear =)